# What most significant changes can user do in the Windows 7 and 2008?

Tags: windows, user-profiles

I mean what changes can user account (not admin) implement that have maximum effect on the system by re-configuring it legally? This is in respect of user account capabilities.

Comment: since your question is incredibly vague (you might want to work on that) i would say "shutting it down" would be at least one high-impact action. If that is not the answer you were looking for, consider changing your question.

Comment: ok, what the difference between administrator and user account capabilities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a summary for XP things (generally still correct for new editions):

> **Administrators**
>
> Adding users to the Users group is the most secure option, because the
> default permissions allotted to this group do not allow members to
> modify operating system settings or other user's data. However, user
> level permissions often do not allow the user to successfully run
> legacy applications. The members of the Users group are only
> guaranteed to be able to run programs that have been certified for
> Windows. For more information on the Certified for Windows Program,
> see the Microsoft Web site. As a result, only trusted personnel should
> be members of this group.
>
> Ideally, administrative access should only be used to:
>
> - Install the operating system and components (such as hardware drivers,
>   system services, and so on).
> - Install Service Packs and Windows Packs.
> - Upgrade the operating system.
> - Repair the operating system.
> - Configure critical operating system parameters (such as password
>   policy, access control, audit policy, kernel mode driver
>   configuration, and so on).
> - Take ownership of files that have become inaccessible.
> - Manage the security and auditing logs.
> - Back up and restore the system.
>
> **Users**
>
> The Users group is the most secure, because the default permissions
> allotted to this group do not allow members to modify operating system
> settings or other users' data.
>
> The Users group provides the most secure environment in which to run
> programs. On a volume formatted with NTFS, the default security
> settings on a newly installed system (but not on an upgraded system)
> are **designed to prevent members of this group from compromising the
> integrity of the operating system and installed programs. Users cannot
> modify systemwide registry settings, operating system files, or
> program files. Users can shut down workstations, but not servers.
> Users can create local groups, but can manage only the local groups
> that they created. They can run certified Windows 2000 or Windows XP
> Professional programs that have been installed or deployed by
> administrators. Users have Full Control over all of their own data
> files (%userprofile%) and their own portion of the registry
> (HKEY_CURRENT_USER)**.
>
> *Emphasis Added*

@TheUser1024's response nails it pretty well.

Note, there are other types of user accounts available as well.  [Source](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/windows_security_default_settings.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: how users can create local groups? it's administrators task